# The Foreign field of $lookup could be the field of nested document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is used to perform a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the “joined” collection for processing in Mongo.

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

Could the `foreignField` be the field of the nested document of `from` collection?

For example, there are two collections as following.

`history` collection

```
 [{
  id:'001',
  history:'today worked',
  child_id:'ch001'
},{
  id:'002',
  history:'working',
  child_id:'ch004'
},{
  id:'003',
  history:'now working'
  child_id:'ch009'
}],
```

`childsgroup` collection

```
[{
  groupid:'g001', name:'group1'
  childs:[{
      id:'ch001',
      info:{name:'a'}
  },{
      id:'ch002',
      info:{name:'a'}
  }]
},{
  groupid:'g002', name:'group1'
  childs:[{
      id:'ch004',
      info:{name:'a'}
  },{
      id:'ch009',
      info:{name:'a'}
  }]
}]
```

so, this `aggregation` code could be executed like this?

```
db.history.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "childsgroup",
         localField: "child_id",
         foreignField: "childs.$.id",
         as: "childinfo"
       }
  }
])
```

So I want to get the result like this.

```
     [{
      id:'001',
      history:'today worked',
      child_id:'ch001',
      childinfo:{
          id:'001',
          history:'today worked',
          child_id:'ch001'
       }
    },  .... ]
```

Isn't this possible?

Comment: What version of mongo you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no positional operator for $lookup but you can use custom `pipeline` in MongoDB 3.6 to define custom join [conditions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries):

```
db.history.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "childsgroup",
            let: { child_id: "$child_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$$child_id", "$childs.id" ] } } },
                { $unwind: "$childs" },
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$childs.id", "$$child_id" ] } } },
                { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$childs" } }
            ],
            as: "childInfo"
        }
    }
])
```

First `$match` added to improve performance: we want to find only those documents from `childsgroup` that contain matching `child_id` and then we can match subdocuments after `$unwind` stage.

Comment: This should be the first stage in `pipeline`. `{ $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$$child_id", "$childs.id" ] } } }` ?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I know what you mean but it returns no results in that case

Comment: Nopes it will return. I have tested it. It is because to  filter out the docs before going to `$unwind` stage.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet that's interesting. Tested on 3.6 and 4.0 and `$eq` returns nothing if gets executed before `$unwind`. Anyway it's a good point to `$unwind` on filtered collection so I've modified my answer and added `$match` with `$in`. Thanks !

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to say. Perfect